# Printing 1 list instead of multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I defined a function that checks for vowels from a input and prints them in a list, it works but it prints multiple lists when I only want it to print one like (['i', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'e'])

Here is my code

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

sentence = input()

def VowelChecker(sentece):
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter in vowels:
            print([letter])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list and then append to it, eventually printing it once after the loop:

```
def print_vowels(sentence):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    vowels_in_sentence = []

    for letter in sentence:
        if letter in vowels:
            vowels_in_sentence.append(letter)
    
    print(vowels_in_sentence)
```

Another way to achieve this would be to use `filter` builtin:

```
def print_vowels(sentence):
    vowels = 'aeuio'
    vowels_in_sentence = filter(lambda letter: letter in vowels, sentence)
    print(vowels_in_sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

sentence = "icebreaker"

def VowelChecker(sentece):
    print([c for c in sentence if c in vowels])

VowelChecker(sentence)
# ['i', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a new list and each time you find a letter, add it to that list. At the end, return that list, so that you can print it.

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

sentence = input()

def VowelChecker(sentece):
    res = []
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter in vowels:
            res.append(letter)
    return res

print(VowelChecker(sentence))
```

Comment: there is no need to use two `for` loops. What this code does it iterate over each letter and then it tries to iterate over every letter (the variable you call `word`), which is a `char` and not iterable